# "Please Select the Default Locales of the PBX" page comes back fairly often in FreePBX

Tags: freepbx

We have installed freePBX 13 on RHEL. Everything was working until today. Today, after logging in to the GUI we are getting "Please Select the Default Locales of the PBX" screen.

[image]

I have observed that it is rendering from **\admin\modules\soundlang\views\oobe.php** file and method “**oobeRequest()**” inside **admin\modules\soundlang\Oobe.class.php** is calling that page.But unable to trace how it is getting triggered. Are there any hooks which are calling this method dynamically?

Can anyone tell me why this screen keeps coming though I have not updated any modules in frePBX. How to fix this issue.

Comment: This sounds like a question for FreePBX forums. There's a value stored in the database that marks OOBE as completed. Perhaps you're doing something to remove or reset it.

Comment: Have you tried press submit?